# My npm package depends on X(say its material-ui), how to avoid the user install X twice?

Tags: javascript, npm

guys, I published an npm package X, with dependency of material-ui, most user using X has already installed material-ui, but some may not. What should I do to make sure those who installed material-ui use their version of material-ui, but for those who don't, I install material-ui myself so X can be properly used?

I looked into it and peerDeps seems to be an option, but people may not install material-ui and still want to use my packages.

Answer (score 1):

Npm is quite clever and will automatically build the optimal tree of dependencies when running npm install to avoid duplicates. To verify this, you can run "npm ls" or "npm ls package-name". If your installation for some reason is not optimal, run "npm dedupe" to re-run the de-duplication process.

If conflicting versions of the same package is required, then the module will be installed multiple times to satisfy the version requirement.

But there are situations where multiple installs are not going to work (react/material-ui being prime examples). In this case, peer dependencies would indeed be the way to go. npm will display a warning if the peer dependency is not met, prompting the user to install material-ui.

There's a great article with more info [here](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2016/08/24/understanding-the-npm-dependency-model/).